# PySide pop-up plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyside

Hi I am not a really expert in Python or in GUI developing and sorry if this question was already posted, I didn't find anything similar.

I am developing with Qt Designer the GUI for a software I wrote, but I have a problem to visualize the plots.
I show here a simplified version of the code.

With Qt Designer I generated 3 button, each of them correspond to a function (sine, cosine, and tangent).
If I click the button "sin" I would like to see the sine function and when I click the button "cos" I would like to overlap this other function on the previous canvas, so to have sine and cosine on the same plot.
and the tangent on another one, and have on the screen both of them at the same time.

I don't want a Matplotlib widget inside the GUI but a pop-up window that appear when I click a button.

I know how to do it when everything is in the same function or similar, but because ShowSin(self) and ShowCos(self) are 2 different function I don't know how to do it.
If for example I modify the code deleting the parenthesis after plt.show in ShowSin(self), when I click the button "sin" nothing happen, when I click "cos" I obtain what I want, the 2 function overlapped, but I would like to see the sine when I click its button.

I also don't understand why I obtain a grey background (as you can see from the attachment), it's not a really problem, but I would like to eliminate.

Do you have any suggestions?

I am working with Python 3.4, Matplotlib 1.5.1, and PySide 1.2.4 on Mac Os.

Thanks a lot!

Ciccio

Image of the program with the gray background:

[image]

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

import sys
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from gui.trig import *

import numpy as np

class Trig(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Set the variable
        self.x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)

        # Set the buttons
        self.ui.sinButton.clicked.connect(self.ShowSin)
        self.ui.cosButton.clicked.connect(self.ShowCos)
        self.ui.tanButton.clicked.connect(self.ShowTan)

    #---------------------------------------------------------

    def ShowSin(self):

        sinx = np.sin(self.x)

        plt.figure('Data')
        plt.plot(self.x, sinx, label='sin(x)')
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('sin(x)')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()

    #---------------------------------------------------------

    def ShowCos(self):

        cosx = np.cos(self.x)

        plt.figure('Data')
        plt.plot(self.x, cosx, label='cos(x)')
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('cos(x)')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()

    #---------------------------------------------------------

    def ShowTan(self):

        tanx = np.tan(self.x)

        plt.figure('tan')
        plt.plot(self.x, tanx, label='tan(x)')
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('tan(x)')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()

    #---------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Trig()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    #app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is the trig.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'trig.ui' 
#
# Created: Tue Mar 29 14:03:31 2016
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(387, 281)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 115, 100))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.sinButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.sinButton.setObjectName("sinButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.sinButton)
        self.cosButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.cosButton.setObjectName("cosButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cosButton)
        self.tanButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.tanButton.setObjectName("tanButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tanButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

 def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.sinButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "sin", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.cosButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "cos", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.tanButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "tan", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Do not use the `matplotlib.pyplot` module together with PySide, it sets up its own eventloop that will interfere with the Qt one. Just create a new Qt window when the button is clicked and embed a Matplotlib plot widget inside it. You can base it on [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html)

Comment: @titusjan thanks for the comment, I will try and let you know